# The product of two uniformly continuous functions on $\Bbb R$ don't have to be uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

I'm to show that the product of two uniformly continuous functions on $\Bbb R$ don't have to be uniformly continuous. I know that the product is iff the two functions are bounded... I'm assuming it would be enough to give an example of uniformly continuous unbounded functions which, when multiplied together, are not uniformly continuous.

As I know $x^2$ is NOT uniformly continuous on $\Bbb R$, would it be enough to say that if $f(x) = g(x) = x$ then $(fg)(x) = x^2$ shows the product need not be uniformly continuous?

Comment: Yes, why wouldn't it be?

Comment: @saulspatz I was just unsure if I should give a more complete explanation using the definition of uniformly continuous including $\epsilon$ and $\delta$

Comment: Well, you might want to explain how you know that $x^2$ is not uniformly continuous using $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$, but I think it's sufficiently obvious that $x$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: @saulspatz yes, I proved it in a previous assignment so I do have that referenced. Thanks!